# C# Web Api Facebook token based authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, owin

I am trying to add Facebook authentication to a C# web api project with default web api template that's supposed to work with a separate Javascript web interface (with React).
However, I am running into a problem of being unable to pass the authorization token from the back-end to front-end. Is there any proper way to do it?

**

### **Detailed description of what I've managed to achieve so far:**

**

Front-end port is 3000, and back-end port is 44378.

The sequence I'm using is the following:

1) First, get all available login providers

```
GET /api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
```

2) Then, use the Url associated with Facebook provider

```
/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44378%2F&state=KXiWds49DMtXLqwrPFsfvus6VfJRh4Gr5dQFq5Q10nE1
```

From this, we get several redirects to Facebook and back to local back-end like so:

[image: redirect list]

After this, the address looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44378/#access_token=[...]&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600&state=qrnh0GIG8ZTWTGh4e603gWLaE7E3GBUK-7dLURg6vus1
```

As far as I can tell, it's a local access token that has no direct connection with Facebook.

3) And this is where I hit the dead end. The redirect URL is on the back-end side, so the front-end cannot gain access to this token. If I manually copypaste the token as **Authorization: Bearer**  into the request header, I can access Web Api, but it's not passed back to the front-end component so I'm getting stuck there.

A thing to note is that after all the redirects the back-end sets the cookie depending on whether the user has a local account: *.AspNet.ExternalCookie* if he doesn't, and *.AspNet.Cookies* if he does, but I haven't been able to find any use for them.

**So the question is: is there any way to pass the local access token to the front-end component?**

For the sake of completeness, here are some relevant code parts:

*Startup.Auth.cs*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using WebApplication4.Providers;
using WebApplication4.Models;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "*",
                AppSecret = "*", //codes hidden
            };

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

*AccountController.cs - just ExternalLogin method*

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
    }

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
    }

    ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

    if (externalLogin == null)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }

    if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
    }

    ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
        externalLogin.ProviderKey));

    bool hasRegistered = user != null;

    if (hasRegistered)
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

         ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
            OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        Authentication.SignIn(identity);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: _“As far as I can tell, it's a local access token that has no direct connection with Facebook”_ - no, that _is_ the FB access token. _“The redirect URL is on the back-end side, so the front-end cannot gain access to this token”_ - and the hash portion of the URL is a merely client-side construct, and does not even get send to the server … Your options are to either catch this on the front-end side, or to chose a different response_type, and get a code you then exchange for a token via a server-side API call, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

Comment: "_no, that is the FB access token_" - are you sure? I've used this token as Authorization Bearer on the API itself, which is why I thought FB token was consumed in one of the redirected calls, and this one was a local access token. Let me confirm this: you're saying that the client side can in fact read the access_token from the # part of the URL?

Comment: Check the section that talks about the `response_type` parameter in above linked documentation.

Comment: I have, but that didn't really clear things for me.

Comment: Why/how not? When you see _"[value] `token`: Response data is included as a URL fragment and contains an access token. Desktop apps must use this setting for response_type. This is most useful when the client will be handling the token."_ ... what question does that leave still open now?

Comment: The question of how to actually pass it to the front-end part, when the redirect process ends up on back-end address. I mean, I got that the token is contained in the Url fragment, but I still don't understand how to actually extract it, if we end up on the server address with a url part that isn't actually sent to the server.